# Is there any other package other than "sentiment" to do Sentiment Analysis in R?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

The "sentiment" package in R was removed from the Cran repository. What are the other packages which can do Sentiment Analysis?

For example, how I can rewrite this using other packages?

```
 library(sentiment)
# CLASSIFY EMOTIONS
classify_emotion(some_txt,algorithm="bayes",verbose=TRUE)
# classify polarity
class_pol = classify_polarity(some_txt, algorithm="bayes")
```

Where documents here is defined as:

```
# DEFINE text
some_txt<- c("I am very happy at stack overflow , excited, and optimistic.",
                "I am very scared from OP question, annoyed, and irritated.")
```

Comment: qdap does a polarity thing but it's low level at this point.  Essentially it's a dictionary lookup system and may not scale well to large projects.  It's intended more for discourse studies.

Comment: Have you looked at the workflows and functions linked to here? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10233087/1036500 Here's a summary of two other methods: https://sites.google.com/site/miningtwitter/questions/sentiment

Comment: you can do this , `library(sos) ;findFn('sentiment analysis')`, you have essentially, `qdap` and `textir` but there is also `tm.plugin.sentiment` for time series .. The `sentiment` package is still exist  in R-Forge also.

Comment: The `qdap::polarity` function is an implementation based on the first link Ben provides but with a custom algorithm.  I'm not happy with it but haven't had time to develop it further yet.

Comment: @user1946217  I add some concrete example to your question..( I am joking for the text example, feel free to edit it)

Comment: @agstudy I do not find the "sentiment" package in R-Forge either. I got the archived version on CRAN. But It isn't loading properly.    `> install.packages("C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/sentiment.zip", repos=NULL)` `Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)` `package ‘sentiment’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked` `> library(sentiment)` `Error in library(sentiment) : ‘sentiment’ is not a valid installed package` Am I missing something

Comment: @TylerRinker Has qdap's polarity abilities improved in the past two years?

Comment: @Dason yes I rewrote the algorithm to be more accurate and faster.  It also takes into account negators (e.g., "It's not good" is ranked as a negative polarity rather than positive as "not" is accounted for).  Other algorithms do not.

Answer (score 12):

I can't find `sentiment` package.This is based on the `tm.plugin.sentiment` package. You can find it [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/?group_id=1048).

First, I create my Corpus:

```
some_txt<- c("I am very happy at stack overflow , excited, and optimistic.",
+              "I am very scared from OP question, annoyed, and irritated.")
 text.corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(some_txt))
```

Then, I apply score on the corpus

```
> text.corpus <- score(text.corpus)
```

The result is stored in the meta :

```
> meta(text.corpus)
  MetaID polarity subjectivity pos_refs_per_ref neg_refs_per_ref senti_diffs_per_ref
1      0        0    0.2857143        0.1428571        0.1428571           0.0000000
2      0       -1    0.1428571        0.0000000        0.1428571          -0.1428571
```

behind the code The `score` function (the default behavior), will pre-procees the corpus using these tm functions:

- tolower
- removePunctuation
- removeNumbers = TRUE,
- removeWords = list(stopwords("english")),
- stripWhitespace
- stemDocument
- minWordLength = 3,

Then, apply the score functions:

- polarity
- subjectivity
- pos_refs_per_ref
- neg_refs_per_ref
- senti_diffs_per_ref

Comment: Each time the score() code throws an error:  scored <- score(corpus.txt)
Error in polarity.TermDocumentMatrix(list(i = c(2L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 12L,  : 
  could not find function "tm_tag_score".  Others have encountered different errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612080/tm-plugin-sentiment-issue-error-could-not-find-function-dmetadata.  Can you advise or should I post a new question?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is new R package called **sentiment140**, required no additional component installation nor language model training.

- **Easy to use**
- **work with Twitter Text**

Cool stuff !

http://github.com/okugami79/sentiment140

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to install 'sentiment' 0.2 in R version 3.0.2

I downloaded the 'sentiment_0.2.tar.gz' from the repository http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/sentiment/

Then I've put the 'sentiment_0.2.tar.gz' in the main directory --> C:

Then I used the command to install packages from local zip:

```
install.packages("C:/sentiment_0.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

This is what I've got:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘C:/sentiment_0.2.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/y65liu/Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

** installing source package 'sentiment' ...

** package 'sentiment' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

** R

** data

** preparing package for lazy loading

** help

** installing help indices

** building package indices

** testing if installed package can be loaded

** DONE (sentiment) ?

When I call the library, the library is regularly loaded with its related packages ('tm', 'Rstem')

You may found documentation on using the sentiment package here:

https://sites.google.com/site/miningtwitter/questions/sentiment/sentiment
```

Answer (score 0):

To install sentiment analysis package use this 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sentiment/index.html
since the packages are quite old already and R cran removed them from their site.

the packages that are required before installing are tm , Rstem , twitteR,ggplot2,plyr,RColorBrewer and wordcloud
it may provide some errors but I worked for me so far :P

Comment: That links to the package which the OP already told us is no longer in CRAN.

Comment: Yes but you can find it at the archives and then install the package manually in R