# tm.plugin.sentiment issue. Error: could not find function "DMetaData"

Tags: r, text, text-mining, tm

I have tried countless times in different ways to run the score() function in the tm.plugin.sentiment package in R but I keep getting the same error. This is a sample code:

```
    library(tm.plugin.webmining)
    library(tm.plugin.sentiment)
    cor <- WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource("NASDAQ:MSFT"))
    tm_tag_score <- tm_term_score
    corpus <- score(cor)
```

This is the error I get:

```
    Error in score(cor) : could not find function "DMetaData"
```

Comment: Update all your packages as to recently underwent some major changes.

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't really help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's caused by the removal of the DMetaData function from the tm package. Refer to this issue on github:

https://github.com/mannau/tm.plugin.sentiment/issues/1

upgrading to the latest version of tm.plugin.sentiment from github using devtools fixed this for me.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("mannau/tm.plugin.sentiment")
```