# Tableau 's R integration for sentiment analysis

Tags: r, tableau-api

could you help me. I saw on youtube the video about sentiment analysis in R, and the man showed how integrate R in Tableau, but he used another package , namely "sentiment", it does not suit me. And he used classify _ function from sentiment package and when he wrote formula in "calculate field" in tableau, he entered this

```
SCRIPT_STR('classify_polarity(.arg,algorithm="Bayes",verbose=TRUE) [,4]',

ATTR([CommentText]))
```

link
https://boraberan.wordpress.com/2013/12/24/sentiment-analysis-in-tableau-with-r/

But  for various reasons,  i work with code, which specified here

http://chengjun.github.io/en/2014/04/sentiment-analysis-with-machine-learning-in-R/

And i don't know ,  on the basis of this code, what formula i must write in the calculate field. Please tell me, what i need  write.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know sentiment has been removed from the cran. but you would find sentiment analysis version of jeffery breen most suitable. 
Check this link for more info.

[Sentiment analysis using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233087/sentiment-analysis-using-r)

Comment: thank you) The main problem is how to work with russian text. Sentiment package is not good for this, because all results are positive, meanwhile in my dataset there are negative phrases too. I.e this package wrong work with russian texts, maybe it's problem in NaiveBayes. Can you change it on MAXENT algorithm?

Comment: @ psysky: what i am talking about is [http://andybromberg.com/sentiment-analysis/] .You can translate the russian text in english before doing the analysis if that helps. or else you could translate the afinn.word list in russian and work so that you can keep you text in russian. then algorithm is pretty much straight forward.