# Forecast Electricity Data using Forecast package ,Where decomposition of Forecasted Data is showing Constant trend issue

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, forecasting, forecastr

I have data from 1 `April` 2008 -31 march 2015 (Daily Data).

I wanted to forecast daily Energy Data.From the graph[Forecast graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KTF1.jpg) ,It is showing that following function is working somehow,so to cross check i decomposed the data(actual + forecasted)[Decompostion of forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT6sj.jpg),It is showing "Constant Trend" from the point of forecast. By I can conclude that my forecasted data is not correct ,it is picking Seasonality but not Trend. 
Where i am doing Wrong ? please suggest !!

```
mydata<-read.csv ("D:/file.csv",header=TRUE);
mydata1<-msts(mydata$Y,seasonal.period=c(7,365.25))
fit<-tbats(mydata1)
plot(forecast(fit))
```

Comment: Hi, Are you using Tableau for this?

Comment: ya i used tableau for forecast.but for multiple seasonality i don not use tableau .i found R more easy than tableau

Comment: please suggest me for this.................its v urgent

Answer (score 0):

I am not well versed in R and also integrating R and Tableau. However you can run r code directly from tableau if your are good in R. Tableau has built in function called script real using which u can invoke r from tableau and get the output to tableau.

You can create the scripts in r and save the code in a directory and then can call that R function using SCRIPT_REAL from tableau.

Below is the code:

```
SCRIPT_REAL('
setwd("/path/to/your/working/dir")
source("your_r_file.r")
your_function(param1 = .arg1, param2 = .arg2,)
', [tableau_param1], [tableau_param2])
```

These links will help you out to begin.

[R Sentiment Analysis in Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034830/tableau-s-r-integration-for-sentiment-analysis)

[R Forecasting with Tableau](https://boraberan.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/using-r-forecasting-packages-from-tableau/)

[Integrating Tableau and R for data analytics in four simple steps](http://www.simafore.com/blog/bid/120209/Integrating-Tableau-and-R-for-data-analytics-in-four-simple-steps)

[Logistic Regression in Tableau using R](https://boraberan.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/logistic-regression-in-tableau-using-r/)

Comment: Thanks For your kind Reply,it is working...but R is open source so i prefer this..and I did many thing on R ,But this forecasting i am totally confused where i am wrong,Why it is not working ,May Any R expert can help me..

Comment: yes but wen i put my daily data ...forecast option seems disable ....i put date as exact date...data (with no avg no sum)

Comment: from few days i am totaly confused i edited my question pls see

Comment: I can send U personally Pls send me your id