# Analysis on Twitter Handle using R

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis, social-media

I want to find tweets of one particular handle using R package.

Let's say for example I want to analyse tweets of David Beckham.

Parameters for Analysis :

1. No. of tweets
2. No. of retweets.
3. No. of tweets which had direct or indirect link with Victoria Beckham.
4. No. of tweets on one particular day.
5. Sentiment analysis.

Please suggest any R package having functionality to accomplish above task.

Answer (score 1):

1-4. Try [twitteR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf)?

5. Here's a relevant [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10233087/sentiment-analysis-using-r)

There is a limit on the number of data points that you can pull free of charge but it's a good place to start.

If you want more data then you might need to buy access to Twitter firehose (e.g. [Gnip](https://gnip.com/sources/twitter/)).